# Flask Dance timing out when deployed to Azure

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

It's me again. I have had more problems getting Flask to work with Azure Active Directory. I am almost there but I just cannot figure out how to get over this hurdle. If anyone can help me, I'd be forever grateful.

Here is what works so far:

- Running my app on the local host with Flask Dance user authentication
- Deploying my app to Azure without any user authentication in it.
- Deploying my app to Azure using the Adal library for user authentication (problem is I want to use Flask Dance instead of Adal because of other features).

So if I run it locally, it works perfectly. If I comment out the few lines of code about Flask Dance in my app, it works perfectly as an Azure website. If I include those lines of code referencing Flask Dance and upload it to Azure, it builds successfully, but when I go to the website, it just stalls and nothing happens until it finally times out with a 500 error. So far Microsoft has not been able to help me either.

I run it just like this:

```
blueprint = make_azure_blueprint(
    client_id="{client_id}",
    client_secret="{client_secret}",
    tenant="{tenant_name}"
)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/getAToken")
```

Then I have a small decorator function checking if the user is logged in that checks if the user is azure authorized and if not, redirects them to the azure login page. All of this works perfectly fine at the local host, so where is it going wrong?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the logs that we can use to diagnose the problem?

Comment: This message is pretty old and I believe I solved it some how or another, but I can't remember how. I suppose I ought to just delete it.